# error D8016: '/ZI' and '/clr' command-line options are incompatible

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, opencv

I am getting the following error in my program:

```
  error D8016: '/ZI' and '/clr' command-line options are incompatible
```

This happens when I put the following lines and enable common runtime in configuration->General (If I dont enable it then the error will come at using system and System::Drawing )

```
#using <system.drawing.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;
```

Actually I will be using some windows library in my code that requires the above dll.

How to solve this issue?

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#using <system.drawing.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
IplImage *source = cvLoadImage( "Image.bmp");
// Here we retrieve a percentage value to a integer
int percent =20;
// declare a destination IplImage object with correct size, depth and channels
  IplImage *destination = cvCreateImage
( cvSize((int)((source->width*percent)/100) , (int)((source->height*percent)/100) ),
                                 source->depth, source->nChannels );
//use cvResize to resize source to a destination image
cvResize(source, destination);
// save image with a name supplied with a second argument
   cvShowImage("new:",destination);
  cvWaitKey(0);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: So remove the `/ZI` option.  It's only debug information.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In visual studio to turn off `/ZI`:

1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
2. Click the C/C++ folder.
3. Click the General property page.
4. Modify the Debug Information Format property - set it to "None"

Comment: I know this is old, but I am having the same issue and tried this solution and am now getting '/clr' and '/Gm' are not compatible...

Comment: @ethancodes Go to the project properties, Under C/C++, Under Code Generation, turn off Enable Minimal Rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading VS will help. Minimum version: 16.11.11

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the Answer by PGP suggests, consider also changing `C/C++ -> Optimization -> Optimization` to *Disabled (/Od)*.

Having it as *Maximum Optimization (Favor Speed) (/O2)* might give you problems when compiling for debug.

-O2 it's a certain level of compile-time optimisation. Google about what it does

Answer (score 1):

In VS2017:

- \ZI is set by C/C++>General>Debug Information Format = Program Database for Edit and Continue
- \GL is set by C/C++>Optimization>Whole Program Optimization = Yes

I copied a configuration that I wanted to use as debug config and ran into that issue.