# '/clr' and '/Za' command-line options are incompatible

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I've been trying to write a c++ dll that could be ran in c#. In Visual Studio, I've added the '/ZctwoPhase-' command line options and turned off "Debug Information Format" as instructed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331318/error-d8016-zi-and-clr-command-line-options-are-incompatible) Howver I still get

> 1>cl : command line error D8016: '/clr' and '/Za' command-line options are incompatible

How can i solve this?

```
// c# dll stuff ->
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void* Create() {
    return (void*) new RPCMapper();
}
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) bool sharpaSetLLAOffsetsElement(RPCMapper* rpc , int a, double b) {
    return rpc->aSetLLAOffsetsElement(a, b);
}
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) bool sharpaSetLLAScaleFactorsElement(RPCMapper * rpc, int a, double b) {
    return rpc->aSetLLAScaleFactorsElement(a, b);
}
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) bool sharpaSetPixelOffsetsElement(RPCMapper * rpc, int a, int b) {
    return rpc->aSetPixelOffsetsElement(a, b);
}
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) bool sharpaSetPixelScaleFactorsElement(RPCMapper * rpc, int a, int b) {
    return rpc->aSetPixelScaleFactorsElement(a, b);
}
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) bool sharpaSetYNumCoefficientsElement(RPCMapper * rpc, int a, double b) {
    return rpc->aSetYNumCoefficientsElement(a, b);
}
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) bool sharpaSetYDenCoefficientsElement(RPCMapper * rpc, int a, double b) {
    return rpc->aSetYDenCoefficientsElement(a, b);
}
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) bool sharpaSetXNumCoefficientsElement(RPCMapper * rpc, int a, double b) {
    return rpc->aSetXNumCoefficientsElement(a, b);
}
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) bool sharpaSetXDenCoefficientsElement(RPCMapper * rpc, int a, double b) {
    return rpc->aSetXDenCoefficientsElement(a, b);
}
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) bool sharpcGenerateBoundingBox(RPCMapper* rpc) {
    return rpc->cGenerateBoundingBox();
}
```

Comment: It appears that `/Za` turns off (all) language extensions. And you can't very well use the CLR features (which certainly are *not* Standard C++) with that enabled. Turn off the /Za flag (in your project's "Properties -> C/C++ -> Language" ... "Disable Language Extensions" = **No**).

Comment: @AdrianMole hmm for me it was already set at "No"

Comment: Check the properties for the file generating the error (not the project) - look at C++ > Command Line.  Remember to check all build configurations.

Comment: Is that the setting on the project and *all* (C++) source files in that project?

Comment: @Kenichi Matsuo, based on my test, I find that it will not occur the problem if I set Disable Language Extensions to be no and rebuild it. Have you rebuilt it after you change the option?